# Creating a new function with lesser arguments by wrapping the old function on it

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, wrapper

Suppose I have an old function, `oldFunction(first, second, third)`. And, all the arguments are mandatory. I want to deprecate the use of 'second' argument, and also not change the code anywhere in my project.

I want to create a new function which does exactly the same thing, with only the first and the third argument.

I was thinking of wrapping the new function with new signature with old function as the wrapper. How can I possibly do that? Hence I will be able to use the new function with only two arguments, but when called by the old name, will the new function be called (because it is wrapped)?

How can I do that?

Comment: You have a problem if you are calling the `oldFunction` from within a wrapper since presumably the `second` argument will modify the output of the `oldFunction`?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have `newFunction(x,y)` defined you can redefine `oldFunction` as:

```
def oldFunction(x,y,z):
    return newFunction(x,z)
```

Comment: How is this not changing the code? This is a pretty bad coding in my opinion. This being said, I agree this solves the OP problem. +1

Comment: @Chinny84 The idea is that existing sections of code which have calls to `oldFunction` can be left as is. Obviously *some* of the code is changing, but only 1) the definition of `newFunction` is added and 2) `oldFunction` is redefined. OP could have been a bit clearer about what they meant by "not change the code anywhere in my project." I read the intended meaning as "not change the code anywhere *else* in my project."

Comment: I know you are correct, and please don't take my words as an attack on your approach, but instead on the original question. Each code modification requires great thought especially if it is within a pre-existing codebase.

Comment: @Chinny84 I didn't take it as an attack. You are surely correct that modifying an existing code base is a tricky business and that OP's approach seems like a problematic way to do so (e.g. how can you really be sure that it is safe to simply drop this third parameter?) Still, I can imagine some reasonable use-cases for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use keyword arguments? This way you could have both:

```
def function(a, b, c=None):
    pass
```

And you can call it `function(a, b)` and also `function(a, b, c)`.